# How do I get these text fields to download into txt file when button clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, text, download

How do I get these text fields (username & password) to download into txt file when button clicked?  (its' just for front end school project).  I know this is not normal practice but I just need to demo a front end product.

My code....

```
<h3>Login</h3>
      <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name">
            <p class="help-block"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group form-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password"     required data-validation-required-message="Incorrect username or password.">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="success"></div>
        <!-- For success/fail messages -->
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"    id="sendMessageButton">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
```

This is code from an example that does what I want but I cannot apply the code to make my form work....

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <style>
   form * {
     display: block;
     margin: 10px;
   }
   </style>
   <script language="Javascript" >
   function download(filename, text) {
     var pom = document.createElement('a');
     pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

   encodeURIComponent(text));
     pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

     pom.style.display = 'none';
     document.body.appendChild(pom);

     pom.click();

     document.body.removeChild(pom);
   }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body>

   <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
     <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
     <textarea rows=1 cols=25 name="text"></textarea>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 1" onclick="getElementById      ('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 1<br>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Option 2" onclick="getElementById      ('problem').value=this.value;"> Option 2<br>
   <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
   <input type="text" name="problem" id="problem">
     <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: wow - thanks for answering so quickly!  I have never used this before.  I found this code and I don't know how to apply this to my code.  All I need is for someone to write in the 'username' and password boxes on my code above and when the button is clicked it downloads the data into a txt file.

Comment: hello Vivek - thanks for your sample code.  I can't get it to work with my code for my login page :-(

Comment: It's not my sample code, it is posted by Vivek. Ask him in the comment section (the "add a comment" link) below the answer if you have any questions or problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to generate and download text file using js -

```js
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    form * {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="test.txt">
    <textarea rows=1 cols=25 name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Reference for [code](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/189/how-to-create-a-file-and-generate-a-download-with-javascript-in-the-browser-without-a-server)

Above code will download file with name written in first `text` box and file data from second `textarea` box

Comment: Hello Vivek - thanks for your sample code. I can't get it to work with my code for my login page :-(

Comment: @Techwannabe I've updated answer as per your html added in question - please accept it if it works as expected

Comment: That works a treat but (sorry I don't think I have been clear)   I need the code at the very top (under my original question) to work so that when the username and password are entered on the form 'Login' and the user presses the 'login' button it then exports the contents of the username box and the password box into the text file ideally without asking you for a file name for the text file (that could just be pre-named 'user.txt'.  Sorry to be a pain

Comment: @Techwannabe that you've to do it by yourself, we're here to help you with the problem and not to solve it for you. You can use this answer as reference for you code and modify the same as you want it to be. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok many thanks @Vivek for your help.  You have been very kind :-)